# Config parameters / Command Line flags for kube-dns?

Tags: configuration, kubernetes, kube-dns

Where are kube-dns command-line / configmap parameters documented?

I miss a short reference doc like the one here for kubernetes dashboard: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Dashboard-arguments

I could (just) look into the code, but even when doing that, the relation between names of cmdline flags vs. configmap param names vs. file param names are not obvious?

And.. What is the preferred way to configure kube-dns? ConfigMap, config file or cmdline arguments, and if doing both, which method has priority over the other?

This question applies to all the standard containers in the kube-dns pod. (kube-dns | sidecar | dnsmasq)

Comment: Is https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/ not sufficient?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas That describes stubDomains and upstreamNameservers pretty well, but from this file it looks like there are more: https://github.com/kubernetes/dns/blob/master/cmd/kube-dns/app/options/options.go ... And some more here: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-the-hard-way/kube-dns.yaml .. It's not like I have no clue what they all do, it's just that it could be nice to have their behavior well-documented, including what happens if you don't set them.